# In WinRT assembly.GetManifestResourceNames() gives no ResourceNames

Tags: windows-runtime

I am using to get the assembly for following

Assembly assembly = Application.Current.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

and i get the ResourceNames form that assembly for using

var resources=assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()

but it gives no resource names in assembly.

Please help me how to achieve it?

Comment: The assumptions that the assembly has *any* resources is just wrong.  That's not the way resources are packaged in a WinRT app.

Comment: @HansPassant is correct. What resources are you trying to access?

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET, I do that:

```
Public Function LoadResourceStr(sResID As String) As String
    Dim ctx As Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext = New Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext()
    ctx.Languages = {Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name}
    Dim rmap As Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceMap = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap.GetSubtree("Resources")
    Return rmap.GetValue(sResID, ctx).ValueAsString
End Function
```

The MainResourceMap is a collection of all resources of application. Important: the files into directories of app (embedded compiled) need is configured to "Content", not "embedded resource". In this case, you can change string ID from "Resources" to "Files".

The sample above show the resource strings into xml files, to translate your app.